# Large List For Random Text/URL - Opi

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript code for random text/url using an external JavaScript, but lets say I have about 100 urls to put in for random text/urls,  What would be the best option? JavaScript or something else?  I would love to be able to use an external .txt file but I'm a newbie when it comes to PHP. Any ideas or code that may help me on this strange question?

heres the JavaScript code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML .01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
var myLinks = [
{href: 'http://www.whatever.com/somepage.htm', text: 'Some Page'},
{href: 'http://www.whatever.com/anotherpage.htm', text: 'Another Page'},
{href: 'http://www.whatever.com/yetanotherpage.htm', text: 'Yet Another Page'} 
];
onload = function(){
var link = myLinks[Math.floor(Math.random() * myLinks.length)],
pageLink = document.getElementById('myLink');
pageLink.href = link.href;
pageLink.firstChild.nodeValue = link.text;
pageLink.target = '_blank';
};
})();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a id="myLink" href="somedefault.htm">Some Default Text</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't learned PHP， If I understand what you say,use PHP random with a text/url assigned to the href attribute of tag a。

Comment: would that load up much faster and smoother than javascipt?

Comment: @ Semaj Rellim，JavaScript run in browser，PHP run in web server